# apt-get connection time out on pivpn

Tags: networking, raspbian-buster, vpn

I have PiVPN installed on a Raspberry Pi (Buster). I can connect from outside my network to the system without issues, I can see local devices, and the internet is routed through the device (I can surf as if I am in the network.)

However, when I run `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
  Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (176.126.240.86). - connect (110: Connection timed out) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (176.126.240.84), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (176.126.240.167), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.135.117), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.135.118), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.145), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.230.122), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.111), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.151), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.227.39), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (176.126.240.86). - connect (110: Connection timed out) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (176.126.240.84), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (176.126.240.167), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.135.117), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.135.118), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.145), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.230.122), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.111), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.151), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.227.39), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Pinging an external DNS-Server `ping -c 3 -W 2 8.8.8.8` doesn't work

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

UFW is installed `sudo ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
DNS                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
DNS (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)



Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
192.168.5.0/24             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on eth0
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

IPv4 is being forwarded `sudo sysctl -p`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Nameserver are set correct `cat /etc/resolv.conf` (first is PiHole, second is Router)

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.5.2
nameserver 192.168.5.1
```

ICMP rules are allowed as by default. `cat /etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

Can you give me a hint, what went wrong? Linux and Networks are not really my field of expertise.

Comment: Does it work when you have completely disabled the firewall?

Comment: Yes, it works when the firewall is disabled. See @Ephemeral answer below. One rule had to be added to allow http port (80) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to allow DNS :

```
sudo ufw allow out 53
```

For your ping command `ICMP rules` is also require you can read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Enable_PING).

```
# allow outbound icmp
-A ufw-before-output -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

For error `Failed to fetch http://...` you need to allow http traffic for port 80.

```
sudo ufw allow out 80
```

After editing the file, run the command:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

Comment: I allowed dns, then disabled and enabled the ufw firewall again. Still no connection.

Comment: please edit your question with your `sudo ufw status` command output

Comment: 'then disabled and enabled the ufw firewall again' and have you check again if dns is allowed ?

Comment: yes i did, it is now in the updated `sudo ufw status` above

Comment: for your ping command `ICMP rule` is also require you can read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Enable_PING)

Comment: for `Failed to fetch http://` ... you need to allow http traffic

Comment: Thank you, added a section on the ICMP rules and allowed `sudo ufw allow http`. See above. No success unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify the rules must be for 'output'. See my edited answer.

Comment: yes, the last two worked for me `sudo ufw allow out 80 & sudo ufw reload`. I reverted the other ones, only 80/out stayed and it works. `sudo ufw allow out 53` was not necessary.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow out 53 was not necessary.` If you want to resolve domain name into an ip addr it is require else it is not require. For example 'nslookup stackexchange.com' command line or `ping domainanme.org` need this rule, webbrowser need this rule etc...

Comment: Yes, different server and ```sudo ufw allow out 53``` was necessary. Also, I had issues there with some ```https``` repositories. Here ```sudo ufw allow out 443``` helped.